# Django test NULL field without hit database

Tags: django, django-orm

I have the following schema:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, blank=True, null=True)
```

Picking up all B objects to template

```
b = B.objects.all()
```

In the template i want to go

```
for n in b:
    n.name
    if n.a:
        do_something()
```

But this is hitting the database because of the Foreign Key, and i only want to know if `a` is null or not. And i dont want to fetch all `A` stuff with a join.

Comment: What if you do `if n.a_id:`? Foreign keys add an extra field to your models ending in `_id` that should allow you to access the actual local field on the `n` model instead of hitting the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a relationship to another model, behind the scenes django is actually using a field called `a_id` to locally store the `id` of the `A` model on the `B` model (it also creates the `id` behind the scenes). Then when you access `b.a` it knows which `A` to select based off of the actual database entry in the `B` table.

So:

`b.a` follows the relationship and hits the database to get the `A` model

`b.a_id` uses the local `b` model's field that contains the `id` that relates to the `A` model

Let me know if that doesn't make sense...